# Network Kernel Density QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, kernel-density

I am looking to do a network based KDE to show hotspots of electrocutions along a power line network.

Does anyone know of a tool/method that I can use in QGIS to do this?

(I am also using OSX operating system)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You can use v.kernel on GRASS. You can acess via processing menu > Toolbox in QGIS.
Documentation with examples: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.kernel.html